# Qt. Перевод QString в ASCII

Tags: qt, ascii

Как преобразовать каждый символ строки `QString` в кодировку *ASCII*?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, Вы ищете [qPrintable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable).

При нежелании использовать готовое, можно написать так: `str.toLocal8Bit().constData()`.